# can we manage session for deleted user?

Tags: security

suppose user is accessing account at the same time admin delete his account then what should happen at front end? can user access his account or redirect to login page??

same if admin inactivated user what should be happen there??

for web site

Comment: What are you asking for? Obviously a user should immediately be locked and any new transactions denied, other than that you are not really making much sense here. Without knowing anything about the platform: Throw a security exception OR redirect the user immediately to a "You are banned" page. For more detailed answer please submit more info.

Comment: suppose i have web application developed in asp.net.
SCENARIO:-user is logged in at front end, at same time i have deleted his account from back end,can user still access his account at front end or redirect to login page??

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773197/how-to-kill-other-users-session

Answer (score 0):

Depends entirely how you set it up.  If you want it to automatically log him out you'd have to manually delete the session after you delete the user from the database.

Comment: can we delete session automatically once account is deleted??

Answer (score 0):

Solution

1. if user deleted 
   logout and redirect user to one page and informed that account is deleted. inform to contact administrator
2. if user inactive
   logout and redirect user to the login page or on some other page of the system and inform that his/her account is inactive. inform to contact administrator

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking user session before any action performed by the user (I simply use the information in session to log them in 'again' and return relevant information back to the session, which makes it also easy to keep track of any account changes the user may have made), thus after admin deletes the account, once user attempts to do anything with is account, the login function/method, or whatever mechanism you use, should return false and set the session accordingly